# exporting wordpress db from godaddy phpmyadmin to local mamp phpmyadmin shows 1062 duplicate entry for key primary

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Trying to export Wordpress production DB from Godaddy and import in local MAMP and I am getting this error.

[image]

Comment: wrong character encoding?

Comment: @ryan how do you fix it?? 
do i do it, itself in phpmyadmin in server??
or before i import in MAMP??
and how do i do it??

Comment: it's just a guess on my part given those replacement characters. i think there are a couple different character encoding settings for mysql databases and tables. figure out how to query for these values and make sure the character encodings match. if they don't change the dest database to the encoding of the source database.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version did you use for the export, and what is the version on the new server for the import?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch 
1) local MAMP phpmyadmin Version information: 4.9.0.1 , 
2) Server phpmyadmin from godaddy looks like: phpMyAdmin 3.5.5

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'c%';` (both servers), and the specifics on how the expert and import were being performed.  Also, MySQL version number on each machine.  Please provide text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest to first change the character encoding from the current location (phpMyAdmin) that the site is running, once you have successfully changed the encoding you can repair the table that is been triggered with the duplication.

By repairing the table you should be able to afterwards not run into such issues. Also from the looks of it thats the **Wordfence** back logs which you can drop if you still encounter a duplicate error (which I doubt that you will run once you have repaired the table after the proper character encoding has been set).

Comment: could you please direct me on how to change the character set for wordpress db. i guess character sets and collations has to match.
also i do not want to touch db in production, so can i use text editor to edit dump file and import locally?? Do not have much experience with what you have suggested, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to a mismatch of the character encoding that the database is being exported from and the default encoding of the new database.

To check this, export a fresh db from Godaddy and search for this line:

```
`meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE
```

Right after COLLATE you should see the encoding string, e.g:

```
`meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
```

So for me, I need to make sure I am importing the database into a new database that supports **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**, but the error you are getting is more common with **utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci** as if your MAMP is out of date it might not support that yet.

**Solution 1**

Create a new Database an set the coallition to match the one you found in your sql file. The coalition setting is right next to where you type the table name:

[image]

**Solution 2**

If the Coalition you need doesn't exist, update MAMP to the latest build and that will have all the latest coalitions and will successfully import for you if you select the matching coalition when creating a new Database.

**Solution 3**

Find and replace **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** (or whatever your encoding type is) and replace it with **utf8_unicode_ci**.  Now import the sql file.

This one is a bit hackey, but it will allow you to import the file, but depending on what you encoding used to be, you might get random symbols not printing out right and will need replaced.

**Sidenote:**
This could be a Wordfence issue, it has tons of tables that hold a lot of content.  I highly reccommend removing it before you export, but make sure you tick the option "Delete Wordfence tables and data on deactivation".

This setting is available in Wordfence -> All Options -> General Wordfence Options

[image]